# Django: order by field of many-to-many relation

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models

Given django models A and B:

```
class A(models.Model):
    things = models.ManyToManyField('B')

class B(models.Model):
    score = models.FloatField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How do I get a list of `A` entities ordered by the `text` of the highest-scoring `B` in `things`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it.   `list` will contain a list of all the objects of model A sorted by the text of each object's highest scoring thing.

```
dict = {}
list = []
for a in A.objects.all():
    dict[a] = a.things.all().order_by("-score")[0].text
for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    list.append(k)
```

There might be a prettier way to write it, but I can't think of one off the top of my head...

Comment: I'm inclined to favour your approach because of its sheer simplicity as compared to crafting raw SQL or juggling tuples and dictionaries as done in Daniel's blog post.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is really hard. Aggregation can help you if you want to sort by the *score*:

```
from django.db.models import Max
A.objects.annotate(highest_b=Max(B__score)).order_by('highest_b')
```

But in effect you want to do two operations: aggregate by the highest score, then sort by the text of the item with that score. That's tricky no matter what language you do it in. I've written about this issue [on my blog](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/) - for your purposes, I think doing it in SQL via the `.raw()` method is probably the easiest.

Comment: Unfortunately, for my application there is potential for the dbms to be different from client to client, so introducing raw SQL queries will hard to be maintain.