# Django Rest Framework Ordering Filter, order by nested list length

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using `OrderingFilter` globally through `settings.py` and it works great.

Now I would like to order on the size of a nested list from a `ManyToManyField`. Is that possible with the default `OrderingFilter`?

If not, is there a way I can do it with a custom filter, while keeping the query param `ordering` in the url (`http://example.com/recipes/?ordering=`). For the sake of consistency.

Oh and the ManyToManyField is a through table one.

These are my `models.py`:

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cook_time = models.FloatField()
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientTag, through=Ingredient)
```

My `serializers.py`:

```py
class IngredientTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IngredientTag
        fields = ('id', 'label')

class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('amount', 'unit', 'ingredient_tag')
        depth = 1

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(source='ingredient_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'ingredients', 'cook_time')
        read_only_fields = ('owner',)
        depth = 2
```

And my `views.py`:

```py
class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows recipes to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all().order_by()
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    permission_classes = (DRYPermissions,)
    ordering_fields = ('cook_time',) #Need ingredient count somewhere?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(source='ingredient_set', many=True)
    ingredients_length = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'ingredients', 'cook_time')
        read_only_fields = ('owner',)
        depth = 2

    def get_ingredients_length(self, obj):
        return obj.ingredients.count()
```

Then order by ingredients_length

## EDIT

In model.py, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682567/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-model):

```
@property
    def ingredient_length(self):
        return self.ingredient_set.count()
```

Comment: First of all you can't use `len` on obj.ingredients. You have to use obj.ingredients.all() or something, right? Second it doesn't work. I get a `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'ingredients_length' into field.` I think I read somewhere that OrderingFilter works on database level so the python calculated fields don't work?

Comment: Thanks for the help. In both cases, I can get the field to show up in my API results, but I still get a FieldError when trying to sort on it. Is my only option to use a custom filter?

Comment: If you only want to order by the manytomany filed. another solution you can override `queryset = Recipe.objects.all()` from Daniel Roseman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309062/django-order-by-field-of-many-to-many-relation.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps me, but I would like to sort on the other fields as well.

Comment: Please post your whole error message, what is after FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'ingredients_length' into field. choices are what?

Comment: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'ingredients_length' into field. Choices are: carbs_relative, cook_time, energy, fat_relative, id, ingredient, ingredients, meal, name, nutritions, owner, owner_id, protein_relative, recipenutrition, source_img, source_url, tags`.

These are bunch of fields I have on my model that I left out in the original question for the sake of simplicity :)